# Store only time in Database that is set by user from time picker ..... Android

Tags: android

I want to store just the time that I convert in Long and later I want to retrieve that time from Database and convert back from Long to time. When I convert back to time from long, it's not the exact time that just I store in data base.(i convert long value back to time from online converter so it was totally different from my stored date)
This is my code :

```
String sehriitime = tvDisplayTime.getText().toString();
        String iftariitime = tvDisplayTime.getText().toString();


        DateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");   
        Date sehrdate = null;

        try {

            sehrdate = (Date) sf.parse(sehriitime);


        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }  
            long lsehrtime = sehrdate.getTime()*-1/1000; 
            long liftrtime = sehrdate.getTime()*-1/1000; 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        String.valueOf(lsehrtime), 3000).show();
        AlarmDB ob = new AlarmDB(SetRamadanTiming.this);
        ob.open();
        ob.RmEntry(lsehrtime); //<------- store in database 
        ob.close();

    }
```

Comment: Why are you converting your date-Time into millisecond and then again reconverting after fetching from database ? You can save the data in database without converting to millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you are losing precision by converting to HH:mm and then comparing it to an unmodified time. HH:mm cannot refer to seconds or milliseconds (or anything smaller than a minute), so the time will be different.

However, I do not see your comparison code so I am not sure what you are comparing against. I am assuming you are comparing against one of your top two lines of code.